# I'm using child mylisting theme on wordpress , is there any way to add a button so that my changes appear on all listing pages between content

Tags: wordpress, themes, listings

I'm using child mylisting theme on wordpress , is there any way to add a button so that my changes appear on all listing pages between content.

when adding the button shows like this

[image: 1]

any way to add button in content area.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use child theme. You can then copy across the appropriate template and add in the code for the button.

It sounds complicated but it's really quite simple. It's all explained in the theme documentation:

https://docs.mylistingtheme.com/article/installing-child-theme/

Comment: sorry i am using child theme , now i am editing my question, can you show demo how to achive this task

Comment: Without seeing the code it's not easy to answer the question. How is the button in the header generated? Can you post a link to the site?

Comment: this is my site link https://www.careerguide.com/career/career-options/creativity-art/accessories-designer

Comment: for generating button in header is a functionality of my listing child theme

Comment: You need to do some coding. You need to copy the existing code from the header and paste into the listing template in your child theme. It's a 5 minute fix for your site developer. If this is a DiY site you can easily find a developer on a freelancer site.